# Hi code masters, I need advise bouncing image using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use this bit of jQuery in a web application. It seems to be working in        jsfiddle, but not when implemented in my application. Here is my code:

```
enter code here

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "style3.css"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.effects.bounce.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
<img class="myimage" src ="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3513354941        /24aaffa670e634a7da9a087bfa83abe6.png">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.myimage').mouseenter(function () {
$(this).effect('bounce', 500);
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This slightly modified code works under Google Chrome:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js""></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.myimage').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).effect('bounce', 500);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img class="myimage" src ="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3513354941/24aaffa670e634a7da9a087bfa83abe6.png">
</body>
</html>
```